# componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot): prevProps is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to React and I am trying to build this simple web app that takes a stock tag as an input and updates the graph based on the performance of the given stock. However, I can't get my graph to update. I tried using componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot), but for some reason prevProps is undefined and I don't know/understand why. I tried searching online and reading the doc file, but I still can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import Search from './Search.js'
import Graph from './Graph.js'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar.js'
import './App.css'
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       
        this.state = {
            data: [{
                x: [],
                close: [],
                decreasing: { line: { color: '#FF0000' } },
                high: [],
                increasing: { line: { color: '#7CFC00' } },
                line: { color: 'rgba(31,119,180,1)' },
                low: [],
                open: [],
                type: 'candlestick',
                xaxis: 'x',
                yaxis: 'y'
            }]
            ,
            layout: {
                width: 1500,
                height: 700,
                font: { color: '#fff' },
                title: { text: 'Stock', xanchor: "left", x: 0 }, paper_bgcolor: '#243b55', plot_bgcolor: '#243b55', yaxis: { showgrid: true, color: '#fff' },
                xaxis: {
                    zeroline: true, color: '#fff', showgrid: true, rangeslider: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                }
            },
            searchfield: '',
            stocktag: ' '
        };
        this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmitSearch = this.onSubmitSearch.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#243b55';
        this.loadGraphInfo();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
        console.log(prevProps.stocktag);
        console.log(prevState.stocktag);

        if (prevProps.stocktag !== prevState.stocktag) {
           //this.fetchData('SPY');
       }
   }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {
        var search = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ stocktag: search });
    }

    onSubmitSearch = (e) => {
        var search = this.state.searchfield;
        this.setState({ stocktag: search });
    }

    fetchData(stock) {
        //GET DATA
        //UPDATE STATE
    }

    loadGraphInfo() {     

        if (this.state.stocktag == ' ') {
            this.fetchData('SPY');
        } else {
            this.fetchData(this.state.stocktag);
        }

       
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App" >
                <Sidebar />
                <Search searchChange={this.onSearchChange} submitChange={this.onSubmitSearch} />
               <Graph data={this.state.data} layout={this.state.layout} />
            </div>
           
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Search.css'

const Search = ({ searchChange, submitChange }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="SearchCompInput">
                <input class="SearchBar" type="text" onChange={searchChange}/>
            </div>
            <div class="SearchCompButton">
                <button class="SearchButton" onClick={submitChange}>Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1):

The prevProps.stocktag is undefined because you didn't pass any props to App component. Try this in your index.js you will see preProps value but actually it does not make any sense.

```
render(<App stocktag='' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> 

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
        console.log(prevProps.stocktag);
        console.log(prevState.stocktag);

        if (prevProps.stocktag !== prevState.stocktag) {
           //this.fetchData('SPY');
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure on what you are trying to accomplish here but the first thing I notice is you setState of stocktag to this.state.searchfield which is ' ' in your onSubmitSearch function.

```
    onSearchChange = (event) => {
        var search = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ stocktag: search });
    }

    onSubmitSearch = (e) => {
        var search = this.state.searchfield;
        this.setState({ stocktag: search });
    }
```

Add I will also like to add that it is good practice to set value of input to a state value like so

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import './Search.css'

const Search = ({ searchChange, submitChange }) => {
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value)
    searchChange(e)
  }
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="SearchCompInput">
                <input class="SearchBar" type="text" value = {inputValue} onChange={handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div class="SearchCompButton">
                <button class="SearchButton" onClick={submitChange}>Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it was because there was a child class that was calling `super.componentDidUpdate()` WITHOUT passing in the parameters. So the child class looked something like:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
      super.componentDidUpdate();
      ... <-- other stuff
  }
```

And I had to change it to:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      super.componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState);
      ... <-- other stuff
  }
```